# Is there a simple interface from which I can extract average summer temperature and humidity for a list of latitude and longitudes?

Tags: data, climate

I am interested in finding the summer average (either climatalogical mean or for a specific year) relative humidity and temperature for a set of globally distributed latitude and longitude coordinates.

What I need are mean values for June, July, and August.

I would prefer to use actual observed values, but a reanalysis (such as NARR or CRU-NCEP would suffice). Is there a web-based interface from which I can obtain this information?

The closest that I have come to this

- [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=climate+latitude+40.5%2C+longitude+-98.5), but they only provide rainfall and temperature, not relative humidity
- [worldclim.org](http://worldclim.org) looks promising, but requires me to download all of the data before using another program to extract information; it also does not have relative humidity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Weather Underground users can now access daily weather conditions
>   dating back six years in most cities around the world. Historical
>   weather information such as maximum and minimum temperatures,
>   precipitation, humidity and winds are available for use by
>   researchers, travelers, event planners and weather buffs free of
>   charge. The databank was recently expanded to include hourly weather
>   figures beginning with the 1999 archives in most markets.

http://www.wunderground.com/about/pr/news.asp?date=19990412

**Use the API to access this data**

Historical Request Example (San Fransisco Airport) on 18th October 2010.

http://api.wunderground.com/api/YOUR_API_KEY/history_20101018/q/SFO.json

```
Share Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

X-CreationTime:
    0.262
Date:
    Wed, 17 Oct 2012 13:27:47 GMT
Content-Length:
    25571
Expires:
    Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie:
    DT=##################v4; path=/; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT; domain=.wunderground.com
Content-Type:
    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Connection:
    close
Server:
    Apache/1.3.33 (Unix) PHP/4.4.0
Pragma:
    no-cache
Cache-Control:
    no-cache, must-revalidate, no-cache="Set-Cookie", private


{
  "response": {
    "version": "0.1",
    "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
    "features": {
      "history": 1
    }
  },
  "history": {
    "date": {
      "pretty": "October 18, 2010",
      "year": "2010",
      "mon": "10",
      "mday": "18",
      "hour": "12",
      "min": "00",
      "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    "utcdate": {
      "pretty": "October 18, 2010",
      "year": "2010",
      "mon": "10",
      "mday": "18",
      "hour": "19",
      "min": "00",
      "tzname": "UTC"
    },
    "observations": [
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "12:56 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "00",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "7:56 AM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "07",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "15.0",
        "tempi": "59.0",
        "dewptm": "8.3",
        "dewpti": "46.9",
        "hum": "64",
        "wspdm": "0.0",
        "wspdi": "0.0",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "0",
        "wdire": "North",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1017.9",
        "pressurei": "30.06",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "icon": "mostlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 180756Z 00000KT 10SM FEW017 BKN110 15/08 A3006 RMK AO2 SLP179 T01500083 401560144"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "1:56 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "01",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "8:56 AM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "08",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "14.4",
        "tempi": "57.9",
        "dewptm": "8.9",
        "dewpti": "48.0",
        "hum": "70",
        "wspdm": "9.3",
        "wspdi": "5.8",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "180",
        "wdire": "South",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1017.5",
        "pressurei": "30.05",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Scattered Clouds",
        "icon": "partlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 180856Z 18005KT 10SM FEW017 SCT120 14/09 A3005 RMK AO2 SLP175 T01440089 58009"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "2:56 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "02",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "9:56 AM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "09",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "13.9",
        "tempi": "57.0",
        "dewptm": "8.3",
        "dewpti": "46.9",
        "hum": "69",
        "wspdm": "0.0",
        "wspdi": "0.0",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "0",
        "wdire": "North",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1017.9",
        "pressurei": "30.06",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Scattered Clouds",
        "icon": "partlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 180956Z 00000KT 10SM R28R/3500VP6000FT FEW017 SCT120 14/08 A3006 RMK AO2 SLP179 T01390083"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "3:56 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "03",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "10:56 AM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "10",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "12.8",
        "tempi": "55.0",
        "dewptm": "8.3",
        "dewpti": "46.9",
        "hum": "74",
        "wspdm": "9.3",
        "wspdi": "5.8",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "220",
        "wdire": "SW",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1017.3",
        "pressurei": "30.04",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "icon": "mostlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 181056Z 22005KT 10SM BKN017 BKN120 13/08 A3004 RMK AO2 SLP173 T01280083 $"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "4:56 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "04",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "11:56 AM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "11",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "13.9",
        "tempi": "57.0",
        "dewptm": "8.9",
        "dewpti": "48.0",
        "hum": "72",
        "wspdm": "0.0",
        "wspdi": "0.0",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "0",
        "wdire": "North",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1017.3",
        "pressurei": "30.04",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Overcast",
        "icon": "cloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 181156Z 00000KT 10SM BKN015 OVC017 14/09 A3004 RMK AO2 SLP173 70005 T01390089 10150 20122 58002"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "5:56 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "05",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "12:56 PM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "12",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "15.0",
        "tempi": "59.0",
        "dewptm": "9.4",
        "dewpti": "48.9",
        "hum": "69",
        "wspdm": "11.1",
        "wspdi": "6.9",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "150",
        "wdire": "SSE",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1017.0",
        "pressurei": "30.04",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "icon": "mostlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 181256Z 15006KT 10SM BKN014 BKN017 15/09 A3003 RMK AO2 SLP170 T01500094"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "6:56 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "06",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "1:56 PM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "13",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "15.0",
        "tempi": "59.0",
        "dewptm": "9.4",
        "dewpti": "48.9",
        "hum": "69",
        "wspdm": "7.4",
        "wspdi": "4.6",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "160",
        "wdire": "SSE",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1017.6",
        "pressurei": "30.05",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Overcast",
        "icon": "cloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 181356Z 16004KT 10SM OVC014 15/09 A3005 RMK AO2 SLP176 T01500094"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "7:56 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "07",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "2:56 PM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "14",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "15.0",
        "tempi": "59.0",
        "dewptm": "9.4",
        "dewpti": "48.9",
        "hum": "69",
        "wspdm": "7.4",
        "wspdi": "4.6",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "290",
        "wdire": "WNW",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1017.8",
        "pressurei": "30.06",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Overcast",
        "icon": "cloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 181456Z 29004KT 10SM OVC014 15/09 A3006 RMK AO2 SLP178 T01500094 53005"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "8:56 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "08",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "3:56 PM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "15",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "15.6",
        "tempi": "60.1",
        "dewptm": "10.0",
        "dewpti": "50.0",
        "hum": "69",
        "wspdm": "7.4",
        "wspdi": "4.6",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "180",
        "wdire": "South",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1018.1",
        "pressurei": "30.07",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Overcast",
        "icon": "cloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 181556Z 18004KT 10SM OVC014 16/10 A3007 RMK AO2 SLP181 T01560100"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "9:12 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "09",
          "min": "12",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "4:12 PM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "16",
          "min": "12",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "16.0",
        "tempi": "60.8",
        "dewptm": "10.0",
        "dewpti": "50.0",
        "hum": "68",
        "wspdm": "5.6",
        "wspdi": "3.5",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "0",
        "wdire": "Variable",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1017.8",
        "pressurei": "30.06",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "icon": "mostlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "SPECI KSFO 181612Z VRB03KT 10SM SCT014 BKN160 16/10 A3006 RMK AO2"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "9:56 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "09",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "4:56 PM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "16",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "17.2",
        "tempi": "63.0",
        "dewptm": "10.6",
        "dewpti": "51.1",
        "hum": "65",
        "wspdm": "0.0",
        "wspdi": "0.0",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "0",
        "wdire": "North",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1018.2",
        "pressurei": "30.07",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "icon": "mostlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 181656Z 00000KT 10SM SCT014 BKN160 17/11 A3007 RMK AO2 SLP182 T01720106"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "10:56 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "10",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "5:56 PM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "17",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "17.2",
        "tempi": "63.0",
        "dewptm": "10.6",
        "dewpti": "51.1",
        "hum": "65",
        "wspdm": "0.0",
        "wspdi": "0.0",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "0",
        "wdire": "North",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1018.0",
        "pressurei": "30.06",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "icon": "mostlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 181756Z 00000KT 10SM FEW014 BKN160 17/11 A3006 RMK AO2 SLP180 T01720106 10178 20139 50002"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "11:56 AM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "11",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "6:56 PM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "18",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "18.3",
        "tempi": "64.9",
        "dewptm": "10.6",
        "dewpti": "51.1",
        "hum": "61",
        "wspdm": "9.3",
        "wspdi": "5.8",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "330",
        "wdire": "NNW",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1017.8",
        "pressurei": "30.06",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "icon": "mostlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 181856Z 33005KT 10SM FEW010 SCT160 BKN180 18/11 A3006 RMK AO2 SLP178 T01830106"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "12:56 PM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "12",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "7:56 PM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "19",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "18.3",
        "tempi": "64.9",
        "dewptm": "10.0",
        "dewpti": "50.0",
        "hum": "58",
        "wspdm": "24.1",
        "wspdi": "15.0",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "300",
        "wdire": "WNW",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1017.1",
        "pressurei": "30.04",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Partly Cloudy",
        "icon": "partlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 181956Z 30013KT 10SM FEW010 18/10 A3004 RMK AO2 SLP171 T01830100"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "1:56 PM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "13",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "8:56 PM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "20",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "18.3",
        "tempi": "64.9",
        "dewptm": "10.0",
        "dewpti": "50.0",
        "hum": "58",
        "wspdm": "24.1",
        "wspdi": "15.0",
        "wgustm": "37.0",
        "wgusti": "23.0",
        "wdird": "300",
        "wdire": "WNW",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1016.7",
        "pressurei": "30.03",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Partly Cloudy",
        "icon": "partlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 182056Z 30013G20KT 10SM R28R/2200VP6000FT FEW010 18/10 A3003 RMK AO2 SLP167 T01830100 58013 $"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "2:56 PM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "14",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "9:56 PM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "21",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "18.9",
        "tempi": "66.0",
        "dewptm": "10.0",
        "dewpti": "50.0",
        "hum": "56",
        "wspdm": "20.4",
        "wspdi": "12.7",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "290",
        "wdire": "WNW",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1016.1",
        "pressurei": "30.01",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Partly Cloudy",
        "icon": "partlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 182156Z 29011KT 10SM FEW010 19/10 A3001 RMK AO2 SLP161 T01890100 $"
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "pretty": "3:56 PM PDT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "15",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "utcdate": {
          "pretty": "10:56 PM GMT on October 18, 2010",
          "year": "2010",
          "mon": "10",
          "mday": "18",
          "hour": "22",
          "min": "56",
          "tzname": "UTC"
        },
        "tempm": "18.3",
        "tempi": "64.9",
        "dewptm": "10.0",
        "dewpti": "50.0",
        "hum": "58",
        "wspdm": "24.1",
        "wspdi": "15.0",
        "wgustm": "-9999.0",
        "wgusti": "-9999.0",
        "wdird": "310",
        "wdire": "NW",
        "vism": "16.1",
        "visi": "10.0",
        "pressurem": "1015.7",
        "pressurei": "30.00",
        "windchillm": "-999",
        "windchilli": "-999",
        "heatindexm": "-9999",
        "heatindexi": "-9999",
        "precipm": "-9999.00",
        "precipi": "-9999.00",
        "conds": "Partly Cloudy",
        "icon": "partlycloudy",
        "fog": "0",
        "rain": "0",
        "snow": "0",
        "hail": "0",
        "thunder": "0",
        "tornado": "0",
        "metar": "METAR KSFO 182256Z 31013KT 10SM FEW010 18/10 A3000 RMK AO2 SLP157
```

truncated for GIS Stack Exchange.

http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/
(can be setup in 5 minutes)

For Lat/Lngs you need to add the GeoLookUp request:

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/YOUR_API_KEY/geolookup/q/37.776289,-122.395234.json
http://api.wunderground.com/api/YOUR_API_KEY/geolookup/q/CA/San_Francisco.json
```

Comment: That is a phenomenal resource! And there is a command-line interface too https://github.com/sramsay/wu! Could you give an example of how I could query, e.g., daily average temperature and relative humidity for a given lat/lon?

Comment: Have created a json historical request/response example (San Fransisco Airport) on 18th October 2010. See updated answer (full response was truncate as GIS SE has a limitation on the amount of characters you can have in an answer)

Comment: This is working very well ... but the closest that I have gotten to what I need is the "planner" feature to get climatealogical means for a date range, e.g. http://api.wunderground.com/api/MY_API_KEY/planner_06010831/q/7.776289,-122.395234.xml. It returns Dew Point instead of Relative Humidity; but there is a sufficient way to estimate RH.

Comment: argggh ... it seems that the conversion from dewpoint to RH is non-trivial (as discussed by [Lawrence 2005](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/BAMS-86-2-225))

Comment: I asked how to solve t_d = f(rh) at [physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41044/8033)

Comment: http://andrew.rsmas.miami.edu/bmcnoldy/Humidity.html

Comment: thanks for the link - this is what I needed: http://andrew.rsmas.miami.edu/bmcnoldy/humidity_conversions.pdf

Comment: glad to assist - hope you make use of the good weather resources out there. Weather is fascinating subject.