# Extracting climate data for given coordinates from interface?

Tags: data, climate

I have my own dataset of latitudes and longitudes. I need to extract annual average climatic variables (Rainfall, temperature,sunshine etc) for this specific data set. I tried [WorldClim](http://worldclim.org/) but it requires me to download other software to process it. I tried to use these databases from [Is there a simple interface from which I can extract average summer temperature and humidity for a list of latitude and longitudes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36892) but it appears that I need to input each value of long-lat to get climate data here at [Weather Underground](https://www.wunderground.com/history/).

Is there an easier database, where I simply import my lat-longs from excel/csv and get the required climate data?